# Font too thin and lines disappearing

Tags: fonts, typography

I am having issues getting a nice font for my paper as whatever I try, the serif font just looks way too thin in places and parts of characters are disappearing.

[image]
[image]

You can see it in the "A", "e", "g" "s", "o" and some other places.

My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,margin=0.85in,bmargin=2cm,footskip=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,theoremref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Thesis},
    colorlinks=true, linkcolor=doc!90,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true
}
\usepackage{multicol,array}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}
\begin{document}


This chapter will describe a language modelling framework that seeks to solve the previously described problems. The framework automatically induces a hierarchical, graph based N-Gram structure from raw text, which is easy to explain, predict and efficiently updateable. The structure models the text as a hyperedge which has been compressed into a grammar-like structure of nested hyperedges. The structure avoids repetitions and other redundancy while maintaining all of the containment relations between elements which are used for a count-based language modelling.


\end{document}
```

I compile in vs-code using Latex Workshop using the `lualatex` command:

```
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "lualatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "--output-directory=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
    ],
```

Comment: unrelated but this comment is completely wrong: `\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) `

Comment: As always, it would help if you made your example have some text and showed the output of the posted code, not a different document, then people can compare and debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay, good to know, its from a template, so not my fault :D

Comment: never use weird templates and never include packages you are not using.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is literally all there is to it.. in the document I can just write only text and it gives the same effect. There is nothing else in the preamble.

Comment: If I add `\begin{document}

Abcdefghijk This chapter will describe

\end{document}`  I get the following text in linux libertine which doesn't seem to be the font in the image you show [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evsIe.png)

Comment: Then  make an example, why make us do it, and show the output of the example, as I just did in previous comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is exactly what the example would contain and its just the same as I have shown in the picture. Maybe its about how I compile?

Comment: Show your log, it looks to me like you dont have linux libertine and that you are using some bitmap cm fonts (perhaps you have miktex without installing cm-super)

Comment: why are you using lualatex with T1 encoding?? (You just added this information:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why not? I can't post the entire log as its too long, but it does show that it does not find the font. When I remove `[T1]` from the `fontenc` import it works.

Comment: luatex is set up for unicode fonts never use inputenc or fontenc packages with it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So should I remove the inputeenc and fontenc imports entirely?

Comment: as I say, never use them with luatex. inputenc does no harm as the _only_ thing it does if used with luatex is give a warning that it should not be used (don't ignore warnings:-) but as you see; using fontenc will break stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code produces

[image]

Your image does not appear to be using Linux Libertine, which can not happen unless you got an error or warning about missing files. (After any error the pdf is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid)

what is the ouput of `pdffonts` on your pdf, it should be:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
KYKDBY+LinLibertineT                 Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     11  0
```

The document is set up for 8 bit fonts: if you use lualatex you get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/LinLibertine(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 112.
```

so uses cm fonts not linux libertine. It looks as if you only have bitmap T1 fonts installed (which means most likely you are usiung miktex and have not installed the cm-super package with type1 cm fonts)

Comment: I am using TexLive and it shows cm-super as installed.. I removed `[T1]` from `fontenc` and now it shows the libertine font

Comment: that explains why you are getting cm fonts, not why they rendered so poorly, what does `pdffonts` report, type1 or type 3? @stimulate

Comment: `QZOAHE+LinLibertineO  CID Type 0C` and `RADTPX+LinLibertineMO  CID Type 0C`

Comment: no, that's after you removed `T1` I guess, what does it say for the version in the question. @stimulate

Comment: It does say Type 1 if I use fontenc with T1. My main question is actually how do I change the font of my document in general. It seems like it is different for every font and I can only get two fonts to work currently. How is that the state of the ecosystem of Latex? There must be a better way to select fonts than to install random packages with various encodings which may or may not work. I am kinda forced to use libertinus now because its the only font I can get to work, even though I don't particularly like it. But its still better than the default..

Comment: with luatex you usually don't need any font packages at all, just load fontspec and then select the font you want. There are no "random encodings" involved as you just need OpenType Unicode encoded fonts. @stimulate

Comment: So I should use fontspec with setmainfont then? ... That seems to work much better.. I wonder why that is so hidden in all the advice I find online..

Comment: well if you don't want to mess with font-specific packages, yes. Of course for some fonts, the package author may know more about the font than you eg options to select funky swash capitals but if you just want to load a font from your system and have latex figure out matching italic and bold versions, then fontspec is your friend. The `libertine` package you use here is essentially:  if luatex just load fontspec else if pdftex do lots of stuff loading tex-specific font subsets @stimulate